# Monitoring some folders with auditd doesn't produce any log

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, monitoring, audit

I'm setting up auditd rules on an Ubuntu 22.04 server (auditd version 1:3.0.7-1build1 - amd64).

I'm setting up rules to monitor writes on some specific directories.

If I add rules to monitor /etc, I get correct logs when files are written in /etc or subfolders.

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -F dir=/etc -F perm=w -F key=write-etc
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -F dir=/etc -F perm=w -F key=write-etc
```

However, the same type of rules on /root doesn't produce log when I write to files under /root. I have the same problem with /home.

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -F dir=/root -F perm=w -F key=write-root
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -F dir=/root -F perm=w -F key=write-root
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -F dir=/home -F perm=w -F key=write-home
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -F dir=/home -F perm=w -F key=write-home
```

I thought it might be a permission issue or something related, but if I add rules to monitor the whole filesystem, then I get logs under this rule for file modifications under /root and /home (but I don't want to keep this rule as it would be to verbose).

```
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -F dir=/ -F perm=w -F key=write-all
-a always,exit -F arch=b32 -F dir=/ -F perm=w -F key=write-all
```

In case it matters: beside /boot, everything is under a single partition, so /etc, /home and /root are on the same partition.

Any idea why the write-root and write-home rules don't work and how to fix them?